# Fire a POST Request using Google Sheets (on Form Submit)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I used a Google Sheet form as a newsletter registration form.
In the response form i've built a Formula which builts the request.

Column A has a timestamp
Column B the e-mail adress

Column C builts the request:
Example Output

> http://newsletter.request.com/automated/action.jsp?action=SubscribetoNL&pw=XXX&email=xx@xx.com

Is there a way to have a script fire (click on or use POST) the newly created request on form submit?

thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can not fire POST request on Form submit, but you can use of trigger functionality. You can set a trigger which is executed as soon as the form is submitted submitted. As soon as form is submitted, your custom function will fire, you can do something like this in that function,

```
var url =  UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://newsletter.request.com/automated/action.jsp?action=SubscribetoNL&pw=XXX&email=xx@xx.com');
  var responseCode = url.getResponseCode();
  if(responseCode == 200) {
    //do your own stuff
  } else {
    //do your own thing
  }
```

Currently, doPost() is only available for standalone web apps. Refer this help [article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/index#doget_and_dopost) about doPost() and doGet().